# it is recommended to load add-ons in .zip by connect magento

Tags: magento-1.9

It is advisable to create an extension and adapt it so that it can be installed compressed when connecting magento.
Or better yet, send the files to the clients so they can copy and paste them manually to your server, it has happened to me that in some extensions I could not install the compressed connection to Magento

Comment: Hello.  This is an English only forum.  Please post your question on [The Spanish Language Stack Exchange](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I am not sure if this helps anyone, but this is what Google Translate gave me: `It is advisable to create an extension and adapt to upload in the compressed way or better give the files to the client to upload manually because there are some extensions that can not be uploaded by compressed`